# Initi and write array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

In my h file I declare a var that later should be an array:

```
@interface myClass : CCNode {
  CGPoint *mVertices;
}

@end
```

In my init method:

```
mVertices = malloc(size * size * sizeof(CGPoint));

mVertices[0][0] = ccp(0,0);
```

At this last line I get an error **Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer**.
Why do I get this error and how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is not two dimensional. It's just a list of vertices.
If you want to allocate space for a dynamic two dimensional array in C you could do:

```
CGPoint** mVertices;
NSInteger nrows = 10;
NSInteger ncolumns = 5;
mVertices = calloc(sizeof(CGPoint*), nrows);
if(mVertices == NULL){NSLog(@"Not enough memory to allocate array.");}
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    mVertices[i] = calloc(sizeof(CGPoint), ncolumns);
    if(mVertices[i] == NULL){NSLog(@"Not enough memory to allocate array.");}
}
mVertices[0][5] = CGPointMake(12.0, 24.0);
mVertices[1][5] = CGPointMake(22.0, 24.0);
mVertices[2][5] = CGPointMake(32.0, 24.0);    
mVertices[2][1] = CGPointMake(32.0, 24.0);
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < ncolumns; k++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Point %@", NSStringFromPoint(NSPointFromCGPoint(mVertices[i][k])));
    }
}
```

I used `calloc` instead of `malloc` to get CGPoints initialized with 0.0.

Comment: You can use `NSStringFromCGPoint`. ;-P

Comment: AFAIK that's currently iOS only.

Comment: mVertices[i] = calloc(sizeof(CGPoint), ncolumns);
In this line I get "incompatible type in assignment" error

Answer (score 3):

`mVertices` is a pointer, but you treat it like a two-dimensional array which is not allowed (you may treat it like a one-dimensional array, though).

Creating a *dynamic* multi-dimensional array in (Objective)-C is tricky insofar as the compiler would need to know the size of all but the first dimension to actually compile where in memory the element is situated.

But you can do the calculation yourself:

```
mVertices[(row * size) + column] = ccp(row, column);
```

You might want to define a macro for that:

```
#define VERTICE_ACCESS(row,colum) mVertices[(row * size) + column]
```